# Hidden field value in Stripes (object instead of numeric value)

Tags: java, input, hidden-field, stripes

I have this field in my JSP file:

```
<s:hidden name="testResult.bottle" value="${testResultsActionBean.testResult.bottle.id}" />
```

and I get this:

```
<input name="testResult.bottle" value="package.dto.BottleDto@e8" type="hidden" />
```

But this line of code returns ID, which I need as value in the hidden input:

```
<c:out value="${testResultsActionBean.testResult.bottle.id}"></c:out>
```

How can I get ID as value in input?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you provide package.dto.BottleDto source

Comment: What gets printed by your <c:out> call?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999397/hidden-field-becomes-null-when-binding-it-in-stripes-actionbean. Look there for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripes always prefers the value from the action bean over anything you put in the value attribute.  (Even if the value in the action bean is null)

Use this:

```
<s:hidden name="testResult.bottle.id"/>
```